# The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. Candidates are:

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to use [FindOneAndUpdate](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/reference/driver/crud/writing/#findoneandupdate).

I have a simple model as so:

```
public class CRs
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string documentRef { get; set; }

        // fields and properties
        [BsonExtraElements]
        public BsonDocument CatchAll { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my Put request.

```
        [HttpPut("{documentRef}")]
        public CRs Update(string documentRef, [FromBody] UpdateRequest path)
        {
            var data = this.GetCollection().Find(_ => _.documentRef == documentRef).Limit(1).ToList();

            if (data.Count < 1)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = 400;
                return null;
            }

            var filter = new BsonDocument("documentRef", documentRef);

            var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update
                .Set(path.Path, path.Value);

            var db = Startup.MongoClientHandle.GetDatabase("ioc"); // Get singleton connection.
            var col = db.GetCollection<CRs>("inputs");

            var doc = col.FindOneAndUpdate(filter, update);

            Response.StatusCode = 200;
            return doc;
        }
```

However I get the compiler error:

```
  DocumentController.cs(64, 27): [CS0411] The type arguments for method 'IMongoCollection<CRs>.FindOneAndUpdate<TProjection>(FilterDefinition<CRs>, UpdateDefinition<CRs>, FindOneAndUpdateOptions<CRs, TProjection>, CancellationToken)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

What am I missing, I'm following the example from Mongo pretty much exactly. Thanks.

Edit:

My UpdateRequest looks like so:

```
public class UpdateRequest
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public BsonDocument Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong update / filter type. It needed to be like so.

```
        var builder = Builders<CRs>.Filter;
        var filter = builder.Eq(widget => widget.documentRef, documentRef);


        var builderUpdate = Builders<CRs>.Update;
        var update = builderUpdate.Set(path.Path, path.Value);

        var doc = GetCollection().FindOneAndUpdate(filter, update);
```